# "Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 698 Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Tags: oracle

```
INSERT INTO 
FLAG ("OPT_FLAG_KEY","H_KEY","FIRST_NAME","LAST_NAME", 
      "MIDDLE_NAME","TITLE","CREDENTIALS","ADDRESS_LINE_1",
      "ADDRESS_LINE_2","ADDRESS_LINE_3","CITY","STATE",
      "POSTAL_CODE","PHONE_NUMBER","BUSIN_PHONE","DECEASED",
      "OPT_FLAG","OPT_FLAG_DATE","SOU_KEY","SOU_FILE_ID",
      "SOU_FILE_ID_TEXT","BAT_ID","PHONE_NUMBER_SOURCE","BIRTH_DATE")
VALUES(37009326,4,'Daniel','Boyle',NULL,NULL,NULL,'368  Road',
       NULL,NULL,'Doylown','BVBV',1801,NULL,NULL,'NO','OUT',
       TO_CHAR('10-AUG-16','DD/MM/YYYY'),201,
       TO_DATE(SUBSTR('vhic_pavir_20160810.txt',12,8),YYYYMMDD),
       '2016-08-10',598441,NULL,TO_DATE('03-FEB-1952',DD-MM-YYYY));
```

I have run this query in my DB am getting some error like below

> Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 698
>   Error report
>   SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
>   00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:"

Edit: this is my desc of my table:

```
Name                Null Type          
------------------- ---- ------------- 
OPT_FLAG_KEY             NUMBER(14)    
H_KEY                    NUMBER(14)    
FIRST_NAME               VARCHAR2(50)  
LAST_NAME                VARCHAR2(50)  
MIDDLE_NAME              VARCHAR2(50)  
TITLE                    VARCHAR2(50)  
CREDENTIALS              VARCHAR2(50)  
ADDRESS_LINE_1           VARCHAR2(100) 
ADDRESS_LINE_2           VARCHAR2(100) 
ADDRESS_LINE_3           VARCHAR2(100) 
CITY                     VARCHAR2(50)  
STATE                    VARCHAR2(20)  
POSTAL_CODE              VARCHAR2(20)  
PHONE_NUMBER             VARCHAR2(100) 
BUSIN_PHONE              VARCHAR2(100) 
DECEASED                 VARCHAR2(5)   
OPT_FLAG                 VARCHAR2(10)  
OPT_FLAG_DATE            DATE          
SOU_KEY                  NUMBER(14)    
SOU_FILE_ID              DATE          
SOU_FILE_ID_TEXT         VARCHAR2(20)  
BATCH_ID                 NUMBER(14)    
PHONE_NUMBER_SOURCE      VARCHAR2(100) 
BIRTH_DATE               DATE
```

Comment: can you provide desc table (using desc table_name command) ?

Comment: i cannot give it for all the column here, i have pasted in my answer@abhishek

Comment: what is the table name?

Comment: table name is FLAG

Comment: I don't expect a ORA-00984 error for that reason, but the column names should go without quotes, i.e.  `INSERT INTO FLAG (OPT_FLAG_KEY, H_KEY, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,  MIDDLE_NAME, TITLE, CREDENTIALS, ADDRESS_LINE_1, ADDRESS_LINE_2, ADDRESS_LINE_3, CITY, STATE` etc Hope it helps.

Comment: same error i got for that option @Imzcig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issue with your statement. First, double-quotes are not required on column names (unless you have mixed cases or space), remove them.

- `TO_CHAR('10-AUG-16','DD/MM/YYYY')` -> `10-AUG-16` is a **string**, not a date. Thus it does not make any sense to convert a string to a string
- `TO_DATE(SUBSTR('vhic_pavir_20160810.txt',12,8),YYYYMMDD)` -> Format must be in single-quotes, i.e. `TO_DATE(SUBSTR('vhic_pavir_20160810.txt',12,8),'YYYYMMDD')`
- '2016-08-10' -> do you like to insert a `DATE` value or a string? You provided a string, not a date.
- `TO_DATE('03-FEB-1952',DD-MM-YYYY))` -> Format must be in single-quotes, see above. `MM` means the month number, not the month name.